# Can't compare 2 date pickers

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker, compare

I'm trying to clean up a bit of a project i made earlier this year, I wanted to make a check between 2dates (both are selected using Date Pickers)

My check is simple, trowing a message error saying that the final date had to be bigger than the beggining date
I tried using SelectedDateChanged, Lost Focus, Calender Closed without any success.

My code is this

```
private void dtvencimento_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

   DateTime SelDate = dtinicio.SelectedDate.Value;
   DateTime SelDate2 = dtvencimento.SelectedDate.Value;
   //int result = DateTime.Compare(SelDate, SelDate2);

   if (SelDate > SelDate2)//if (result <= 0)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Data do Vencimento tem de ser maior que data inicial", "Erro", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
   }
   //else
   //{
   //    dtvencimento.Style = null;
   //}

}
```

dtvencimento or SelDate2 is the date that as to be later in the year than the dtinicio or Seldate

Example: `MessageBox.Show(blablabla)` should ocur when dtinicio(SelDate) is 8 March 2014 and dtvencimento or Seldate2 is 10 February 2014

The thing is the event doesn't even start occurring.

Comment: While not completely necessary, it's highly recommended that you employ the MVVM pattern with WPF. Validation is pretty simple then. WPF validation is possible without the MVVM pattern, though. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx#data_validation and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

Comment: 1st i want to appologize, i didnt't even say hello nor thank you in the main post :p
2nd I'm still noob when it comes to programming, and i think i used what you talk about already in other textboxes, like the pattern for emails, or XAML style/setter properties for blank/wrong data on the texboxes.

This is the only window that i use Date Pickers on my project and so the only one i need to compare dates, it seems the right code for the job, but like i said before the event doesn't even start i tried debugging but it wont start...

Comment: You don't "compare DatePickers" because UI is not Data. Read up on MVVM.

Comment: Is the problem that it is not properly comparing the two dates or that your "lostFocus" event is not firing? If the problem is that your event is not firing, we need more information such as how you are binding the event and to what control.

Comment: if you put a break point in your lost focus event, does it break after you change the second date?

Comment: no, it doesnt break that's.
@ HighCore
I'm trying to compare the data.value of the date pickers, since i can save the same data.value in my database for possible future reading why cant i compare them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried handling the `SelectedDateChanged` event like this?:

```
<DatePicker SelectedDateChanged="DatePicker_SelectedDateChanged" />

...

private void DatePicker_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime SelDate = (DateTime)e.AddedItems[0];
    DateTime SelDate2 = dtvencimento.SelectedDate.Value;
    if (SelDate > SelDate2) // put a break point here and check value of SelDate2 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Data do Vencimento tem de ser maior que data inicial", "Erro", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }
}
```

Comment: the breakpoint still doesn't fire :\
I'm probably doing something wrong somewhere else :\
I just tried to add a client, and then it saved so the data is being connected like it should and properly being saved on the database.

Comment: In that case, nobody will be able to help you. Forget your current project for a moment. Start a new WPF Application and use this code... if you can get it working there then at least that's a starting point. You should be able to compare the working example to your code and find the difference(s).

Comment: Sry for taking so long to answer.
I just did that, and bam magic in the new project, my original code works... but in the project i need it it doesn't :\

I can't really see why :?

Comment: OMG I'm going to kill myself lol
Since this is a bit old project i forgot i add another window with date pickers, i was putting the code there and testing the more "main" window that had 2 date pickers.

Ofc it wouldn't break since i wasn't testing on the window i had coded lol -.-

Oh well, original code works when used in Selected Date Changed